# Underscored String to Pascal Case

Tags: python, string

I have a kind of string like, `"PRODUCT_CHANGE_IT_LATER"`. I want to convert it into pascal case like
`ProductChangeItLater`

Answer (score 0):

Title case format can be made use of.

```
def to_pascal(word):
    return word.lower().replace("_", " ").title().replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific helper function, called `capwords` (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#helper-functions))

```
import string
string.capwords(s.replace("_", " "))
```

Comment: What benefit does importing a helper function have over using `str`'s own `title` method?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def to_pascal_case(s):
    return ''.join(current.lower() if prev.isalnum() else current.upper()
                   for prev, current in zip(' ' + s, s) if current.isalnum())
```

https://ideone.com/59OgRV